# Ruby difference between send and instance_eval?

Tags: ruby, send, instance-eval

I know send takes string or symbol with arguments while instance_eval takes string or block, and their difference could be apparent given receivers.

My question is what the '**under the hood**' difference is for the example below?

```
1234.send 'to_s'               # '1234'
1234.instance_eval 'to_s'      # '1234'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send):

> **send(symbol [, args...]) → obj**
>   **send(string [, args...]) → obj**
>
> Invokes the method identified by *symbol*, passing it any arguments specified. [...] When the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a symbol.

and for [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

> **instance_eval(string [, filename [, lineno]] ) → obj**
>   **instance_eval {| | block } → obj**
>
> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (*obj*). In order to set the context, the variable `self` is set to *obj* while the code is executing, giving the code access to *obj*’s instance variables.

So `send` executes a method whereas `instance_eval` executes an arbitrary block of code (as a string or block) with `self` set to the object that you're calling `instance_eval` on.

In your case, there isn't much difference as the string you're handing to `instance_eval` is just a single method. The main difference is that anyone reading your code (including you in six months) will be wondering why you're using `instance_eval` to call a single method.

You might also be interested in [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) and [`BasicObject#__send__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__)

Comment: Great, I am already wondering why I had a single method for `instance_eval`.

Answer (score 10):

Whatever you can do with `send` is a proper subset of that of `instance_eval`. Namely, the argument to `send` has to be a single method (and its arguments), whereas the argument to `instance_method` is an arbitrary code. So whenever you have `send`, you can rewrite it with `instance_eval`, but not vice versa.

However, performancewise, `send` is much faster than `instance_eval` since there is no additional parsing required to execute `send`, whereas `instance_eval` needs to parse the whole argument.

In your example, the result will be the same, but the first one will run faster.