# Basic arithmetic operations with user input

Tags: ruby

I want to make a four-functioning calculator. I tried to make methods that would store operations.

```
def mul
  puts num1*num2
end

def div
  puts num1/num2
end

def sub
  puts num1-num2
end

def add
  puts num1+num2
end

num1=gets.chomp.to_f
op=gets.chomp
num2=gets.chomp.to_f

puts "Multiplication=mul\n Addition=add\n Subtract=sub\n Division=div"
puts ("This is your answer"+num1+op+num2)
```

But I couldn't make the calculator.

I tried running the code, but it won't work. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure you want your function to return the value of `puts`? `puts num1+num2` might not be returning what you think it should. Does `puts num1+num2` and `num1+num2` return the same thing? You can check in IRB.

Comment: I'd suggest to pass parameters to your methods, then return just the result.

Comment: If you want to call methods dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name/26284769

Answer (score 1):

**Best Way** to do so, is

```
def perform_operation(op, a, b)
  op = { 'add' => '+', 'sub' => '-', 'mul' => '*', 'div' => '/' }[op]
  a.send(op, b)
end

num1=gets.chomp.to_f
op=gets.chomp
num2=gets.chomp.to_f

puts "This is your answer", perform_operation(op, num1, num2)
```

If your `op` is +, -, * or / passed by input you can directly do it without method like below,

```
puts "This is your answer", num1.send(op, num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use local variables defined outside a method within that method. Instead, you have to *pass* it as an argument:

```
def mul(num1, num2)
  puts num1 * num2
end
```

You also don't have to use the same variable names, use whatever makes sense in the context of the method:

```
def mul(a, b)
  puts a * b
end

mul(2, 3)
# prints 6
```

Methods usually become more versatile if they do *one* thing. The above implementation multiplies `a` and `b` and then prints the result via `puts`. Let's move the printing outside the method:

```
def mul(a, b)
  a * b
end

puts mul(2, 3)
# prints 6
```

We can now perform actual calculations:

```
x = mul(2, 3) #=> 6
y = mul(2, 5) #=> 10
puts mul(x, y)
# prints 60
```

This wouldn't have been possible with the variant which incorporated `puts`.

---

With user input and output: (using whole numbers for demonstration purposes)

```
print "first factor: "
num1 = gets.to_i

print "second factor: "
num2 = gets.to_i

puts "#{num1} * #{num2} = #{mul(num1, num2)}"
```

Note that `#{...}` is needed to interpolate other values.

Example session:

```
first factor: 2
second factor: 3
2 * 3 = 6
```

---

To have different output based on a given operator, you need a conditional, e.g. a `case` statement:

```
op = gets.chomp

case op
when 'mul'
  puts mul(num1, num2)
when 'add'
  puts add(num1, num2)
# ...
end
```

---

Hope this will get you started.

Comment: I think `#to_i` is not good for calculator. `#to_f` is better

Comment: @mechnicov try `0.1 * 0.2` in IRB – the result is probably not what you expect from a calculator ;-)

Comment: @Stefan `.to_f.round(8)` would be what I probably expect from a calculator :)

Comment: I meant, if you want to know how much will be 2.5 multiplied by 2.5, then instead of 6.25 your variant will write `2 * 2 = 4`. It is not a calculator ;-) So `#to_f` is better I think

Comment: @mechnicov _"It is not a calculator"_ – that's right, this is just some example code. Writing an actual calculator is beyond the scope of this answer. (and I don't think an actual calculator should be floating-point-based)

Answer (score 0):

Once you defined the methods with parameters, for example:

```
def sub(x, y)
  x - y
end

def add(x, y)
  x + y
end
```

Once you gat the variables set by user input (I'm assigning by hard coding just to show):

```
op = "add".to_sym # or user input
num1 = 10 # or user input
num2 = 20 # or user input
```

You can use the [case expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) to select the result to show.
For example:

```
res = case op
  when :add
    add(num1, num2)
  when :sub
    sub(num1, num2)
end
```

So you can show the result as:

```
puts res
```

As mentioned, you can also call the method on the user input using `send`:

- [How to call methods dynamically based on their name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name/26284769)
- [Ruby difference between send and instance_eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047234/ruby-difference-between-send-and-instance-eval)

Answer (score 0):

Using [heredoc](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/) and [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Proc.html)

```
def mul(num1, num2)
  num1 * num2
end

def div(num1, num2)
  num1 / num2
end

def sub(num1, num2)
  num1 - num2
end

def add(num1, num2)
  num1 + num2
end

puts 'First number'
num1 = gets.to_f

puts 'Second number'
num2 = gets.to_f

puts <<-OPERATORS
Multiplication = mul
Addition = add
Subtract = sub
Division = div
OPERATORS

op = method(gets.chomp).to_proc

puts "This is your answer: #{op.call(num1, num2)}"
```

How it works on the example of `String#downcase`:

```
downator = :downcase.to_proc
downator.call('WORD') #=> "word"

# It is equal to
'WORD'.downcase #=> "word"
```

It is because `downator` stores block `proc { |arg| arg.downcase }`

In practice, this property is often used for operations with arrays, for example:

```
['WORD', 'STRING'].map(&:downcase) #=> ["word", "string"]

# It is equal to
['WORD', 'STRING'].map { |arg| arg.downcase } #=> ["word", "string"]
```

Comment: Why not store operations as procs to begin with? In, say, a hash, keyed by op name?

Comment: I tried to follow OP logic. But in any case I late read your comment - @ray has done something similar as you suggest.